# Office 2003 can't open newer Office files

Tags: file-format, microsoft-office-2003

I installed the Office Compatibility Pack for Office 2003 so that I would be able to open, edit, and save newer Office files. I even installed up through Service Pack 3.

However, it doesn't seem to work. I do see an option to save as "Office 2007 file" in each of the programs, so the pack definitely installed. However, when I try opening any of the newer file formats, I get this error message:

[image]

I tried a dozen files and they all have the issue.

On a computer with a newer version of Office, if I Save As the older three letter extension format and then try opening in Office 2003, it works perfectly.

When I go to Event Viewer, I see the following in **Application Log** every time I try opening an Office 2007 file:

[image]

On a Microsoft support page which (like most of them nowadays) no longer exists - [but is cached by Bing](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=word%202003%20there%20was%20an%20error%20opening%20the%20file&d=4624322641729142&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=770K3wJnEA825nqcyLSZGuNuHKLVvsV1) - I found the following article:

> #### You receive an error when trying to open a .docx file in Word 2003 or with the Word Viewer
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> When trying to open a .DOCX file in Word 2003 with the Compatibility
>   Pack or in the Word Viewer with the Compatibility Pack, you receive
>   the following error message:
>
> “there was an error opening the file.” Cause This issue may be caused
>   by the OLE32.dll file not being registered correctly. Resolution
>
> To Try to resolve this issue, follow the steps below:
>
> Close any applications that are running.
>    Open an elevated command prompt. To do this, click Start , click All Programs , click Accessories , right-click Command Prompt , and
>   then click Run as administrator . If you are prompted for an
>   administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or
>   click Allow .
>       Type the following:
>       regsvr32 %SystemRoot%\system32\ole32.dll and then click OK.
>       When you receive the message  "DllRegisterServer in ole32.dll succeeded.", click OK:
>       .
>
> **More Information**
>
> This is one solution that we have seen resolve this error. This may
>   not resolve all issues with this above error.
>
> If you find other solutions for the exact error message above, please
>   edit this article with the additional information. Last Updated: 26
>   Aug 2010

Unfortunately, even after closing Word, trying this from Command Prompt, and trying again, it still doesn't work. The same messages appear in Event Viewer.

What is actually causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

I have already tried uninstalling numerous times. I uninstalled, installed the compatibility pack, and installed Service Pack 3. Doesn't work. For good measured, I uninstalled and installed only the base pack, which seems to come with SP1 already. I get the error dialog much sooner, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is this Windows 98 in 2019?

Comment: @Jason No, it's Windows 2000 Professional SP4

Comment: Try fully uninstalling Office 2003, restart, and then reinstalling it again, adding the compliance update at the end.  See if that works.

Comment: @John I did add it at the end

Comment: Office 2002 came with Windows XP and then Office 2003 came out for XP.  You might wish to try the above on a Windows XP machine

Comment: @John I can't. If I were using XP, I would shoot all the way up to Office 2010, and then the compatibility viewer is unnecessary. I need this to work on 2000.

Comment: Not a real answer but practical solution: if KernelEx is installed, Office 2007 works fine on Windows 2000. So, use O2K7 instead of O2K3, and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you refer  to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/404902/microsoft-office-compatibility-pack-the-converter-failed-to-open-the-file-erro) relevant question on Superuser.

As per that post only Version 1 or 2 of  MS Office compatibility pack is compatible with Windows 2000. Unfortunately all the links therein are dead.

Microsoft has already taken down the download pages for older versions of MS Office compatibility pack. I however found Version 2 at a third party site [here](https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/microsoft-office-compatbility-pack/download).

I personally do not recommend third party downloads, however my virus scan returned the file clean. I tested the setup in a VMWare Virtual Machine and I find that using this version 2 of the converter, xlsx files successfully open in Office 2003 on Windows 2000.

Here's a screenshot from my experiments.

I am not too sure if this will work for you but worth giving a try if third party downloads are acceptable in your organization. If so, still do a thorough virus scan before installing it.

You may need to completely uninstall any of the current converters and their relevant service packs if already installed on your Windows 2000.

[image]

Comment: This is on a personal PC, so it's definitely acceptable if it works. Unfortunately, I continue to receive the same error as before. I didn't try opening a blank XLSX file as you did, but the Word doc (or rather docx) I have been trying continually fails.

Comment: It's not a blank xlsx file. It was a file named book1.xlsx created and saved in Excel 2013 with 2013 features (finer background colors not available in 2003) and then transferred to this VM and opened with v2 of Compatibility pack installed.

Comment: I could simulate your error. All I needed to do was uninstall V2 of Compatibility pack and install a recent one. Now I get the same error when I try to open .xlsx or .docx files. See this image upload https://i.ibb.co/55krXGQ/2000-1.png

Comment: And here https://i.ibb.co/SVjkPHW/2000-2.png for docx files. So I strongly suspect it has something to do with version of compatibility pack. Most likely some other dependencies might be still affecting in your case. If possible try a clean install of MS Office 2003 and v2 of compatibility pack and check again.

Comment: I uninstalled the compatibility viewer completely using Add/Remove Programs and then installed the one you linked me to. The setup interface and the filename were identical, so there's nothing about it to indicate it was different, but assuming it was, that's the result I got. Do you think there are other factors playing into this?

Comment: As per my earlier comment, one suggestion I can give is to do a complete uninstall and reinstall of Office 2003 + SP3 and then install v2 of compatibility pack and check again if that makes any difference.

Comment: I wonder if it's the SP3 part. I don't know if I had SP3

Comment: It's available on Cnet Download site still. If your Office 2003 does not have SP3 (Check Help About from within Office app)better to install it for improved compatibility with the Compatibility Pack.

Comment: I'm not seeing it, where is SP3?

Comment: https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Office-2003-Service-Pack/3000-18483_4-170478.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but it might just work.
It could be that the OLE2 subsystem in W2000 is too old to fully support the compatibility pack. (The "solution" to re-register the OLE2.DLL is also a hint that OLE2 is involved.)
In such cases it does occasionally help to upgrade the OLE2 subsystem as a whole.
Off course Microsoft doesn't offer that as a download anywhere anymore.
But installing the VisualBasic V6 runtime files also upgrades the OLE2 files.
The VB6 runtime is still to be found online here and there.

As was just pointed out to me in the comments. The base VB6 runtime doesn't do it.
There is larger package that consists of the runtime itself and the MDAC libraries (Microsoft Data Access Components).
It is the MDAC part that also updates OLE2 and you probably only need that part.
Latest version is MDAC 2.8 SP1 (if I remember correctly) and is still available from Microsoft.

Comment: I think I installed the files but it still doesn't work. I don't have any DLLs called OLE2, just Oleaut.cab and Oleaut32.cab

Comment: @InterLinked I should have mentioned that. The VB6 runtime comes in 2 versions. The basic runtime and a larger version that consists of the runtime itself and the MDAC libraries (Microsoft Data Access Components). The MDAC part also updates OLE2 and you probably only need that part. Latest version is MDAC 2.8 SP1 (if I remember correctly) and is still available from Microsoft. Will edit the answer.

Comment: @InterLinked MDAC is always supplied as a full install as far as I know. No need for previous version.

Comment: I was able to install it without issues. It successfully and fully installed. Unfortunately, still doesn't work... :(